# Call onKeyDown Delphi

Tags: delphi

If I have an **onKeyPress** event, so I can call it with

```
var theKey : Char;
....
theKey := #13;  // ENTER key
FormKeyPress(Sender,theKey);
```

How to call the same way if I have an **onKeyDown** event ?

Comment: Why are you calling keyboard events at all? They're for responding to user input at the keyboard. If you need to do something in your code, do it in your code directly.

Comment: I just want to find the other way, so I don't need to create other function inside onKeyDown event.

Comment: So you're doing something totally wrong intentionally in order to avoid doing it properly in the first place?

Comment: That's not my question. My question is how to call it? I think it doesn't matter why I use it or not. Is it? At least you can give an answer and then you can questioning it.

Comment: Yeah, free help of course, that's why you can answer it or not :) Give somebody question after they give a question is rather rude too, Ken :)

Comment: Not if it teaches you *not to waste the time writing the code in the first place*. But I've answered your question for you. I don't have to work on your code later, so do what you want. :-)

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes we don't want to changes other codes, because we just need to fix it a little bit and make it easy to see where I add a new code :)

Comment: Ken is right, you are probably doing something wrong. Those quick fixes often come back at you and cost tenfold to fix properly.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.

Comment: It's OK, I just want to know it and test it, especially how to write the 3rd parameter of FormKeyDown(1st,2nd,3rd), TShiftState. I am not use it anymore. It's never wrong if we want to know how to do it. For your information, that code above is not my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's totally wrong for you to want to do this, because keyboard events are designed to handle user input from the keyboard. You should be executing the code you want directly; you can also use that code from within your key events in response to user input, which clearly separates the user interface from the program logic.

With that being said, you can call the event the same way. For instance, to send <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Key := 13;
FormKeyDown(Sender, Key, []);
```

To send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>:

```
Key := Ord('K');
FormKeyDown(Sender, Key, [ssCtrl]);
```

Comment: Ok, Ken. Thanks for your answer and suggestion :) Your code is working, so I just need to put '[]' then. I just need this code sometimes just for checking the condition.